# Как мне вывести всю колонну через сообщение telebot?

Tags: python, sql, telebot

Всем привет, во время работы с базой данных SQL у меня возникла проблема. Я сообщением хотел вывести колонну данных но выводится только первая строчка.
Вот база данных:
[image: Выводится только первая строчка]

Выводится только первая строчка а нужно чтобы выводилась вся колонна product_name

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("orders.db", check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

CREATE_QUERY = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
        user_id int,
        address text,
        orders text,
        chat_id int 
    );
"""

GET_ORDERS = """SELECT product_name FROM cart WHERE user_id= %s;"""

GET_ADDRESS = """SELECT address FROM address WHERE user_id = %s;"""

GET_HOUSE = """SELECT house FROM house WHERE user_id = %s"""

conn.execute(CREATE_QUERY)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: Message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
    list = sqlitе_client.execute_select_command(GET_ORDERS % (user_id,))
    print(list)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, list)



sqlitе_client = SQliteClient("orders.db")
sqlitе_client.create_conn()
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Для получения всех записей используйте ```sqlitе_client.execute_select_command(GET_ORDERS % (user_id,)).fetchall()```

Comment: Все равно выводит только одно сообщение

Comment: 1. Замените имя переменной хранящей в себе записи, оно не должно использовать зарезервированное языком слово `list`.

2. Добавьте в свой вопрос вывод из `print(list)`